# Trouble with sounds in Monogame

Tags: c#, visual-studio, audio, monogame

I am able to load `WAV` files as `SoundEffect` and play them, but any other format, e.g. `MP3`, `WMA`, `OGG` is failing with below exception;

```
Exception thrown: 'SharpDX.SharpDXException' in SharpDX.dll
An unhandled exception of type 'SharpDX.SharpDXException' occurred in SharpDX.dll
HRESULT: [0xC00D36C4], Module: [Unknown], ApiCode: [Unknown/Unknown], Message: The byte stream type of the given URL is unsupported.
```

I am new to `Visual Studio`, and `Monogame` \ `XNA`, and could not find any information on web.

I use the `MonoGame Pipeline` to add the files in contents.
The code is very simple;

```
protected override void LoadContent() {
    song = Content.Load<Song>("test");
    MediaPlayer.Play(song);
}
```

The project is a cross platform desktop project, and using the version 3.6 of `Monogame`

I've tried to use `Song.FromURI()` but still gives me the exact same exception...

Comment: If I recall correctly, an mp3 or similair format needs to be manually changed to be recognised as a 'song'. It's standard recognised as a soundeffect.

Comment: @Steven What does `manually change` mean? Can you expand on that?

Comment: I think multiple people have experienced this before, I went searching a bit and found this, hopefully this can help you further: http://community.monogame.net/t/mp3-in-monogame-c/1906